# Scrapy crawling not working on ASPX website

Tags: javascript, python, asp.net, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping the Madrid Assembly's website, built in aspx, and I have no idea how to simulate clicks on the links where I need to get the corresponding politicians from. I tried this:

```
import scrapy

class AsambleaMadrid(scrapy.Spider):

name        =   "Asamblea_Madrid"
start_urls  =   ['http://www.asambleamadrid.es/ES/QueEsLaAsamblea/ComposiciondelaAsamblea/LosDiputados/Paginas/RelacionAlfabeticaDiputados.aspx']

def parse(self, response):

    for id in response.css('div#moduloBusqueda div.sangria div.sangria ul li a::attr(id)'):
        target                  =   id.extract()
        url                     =   "http://www.asambleamadrid.es/ES/QueEsLaAsamblea/ComposiciondelaAsamblea/LosDiputados/Paginas/RelacionAlfabeticaDiputados.aspx"

        formdata=   {'__EVENTTARGET': target,
                     '__VIEWSTATE': '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',
                     '__EVENTVALIDATION': '/wEWCALIhqvYAwKh2YVvAuDF1KUDAqCK1bUOAqCKybkPAqCKnbQCAqCKsZEJAvejv84Dtkx5dCFr3QGqQD2wsFQh8nP3iq8',
                     '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': 'BAB98CB3',
                     '__REQUESTDIGEST': '0x476239970DCFDABDBBDF638A1F9B026BD43022A10D1D757B05F1071FF3104459B4666F96A47B4845D625BCB2BE0D88C6E150945E8F5D82C189B56A0DA4BC859D'}

        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=url, formdata= formdata, callback=self.takeEachParty)


def takeEachParty(self, response):

     print response.css('ul.listadoVert02 ul li::text').extract()
```

Going into the source code of the website, I can see how links look like, and how they send the JavaScript query. This is one of the links I need to access:

```
<a id="ctl00_m_g_36ea0310_893d_4a19_9ed1_88a133d06423_ctl00_Repeater1_ctl00_lnk_Grupo" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$m$g_36ea0310_893d_4a19_9ed1_88a133d06423$ctl00$Repeater1$ctl00$lnk_Grupo&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">Grupo Parlamentario Popular de la Asamblea de Madrid</a>
```

I have been reading so many articles about, but probably the problem is my ignorance in respect.

Thanks in advance.

**EDITED:**

**SOLUTION:** I finally did it! Translating the very helpul code from Padraic Cunningham into Scrapy way. As I specified the issue for Scrapy, I want to post the result just in case someone has the same problem as I had.

So here it goes:

```
import scrapy
import js2xml

class AsambleaMadrid(scrapy.Spider):

     name        =   "AsambleaMadrid"
     start_urls  =   ['http://www.asambleamadrid.es/ES/QueEsLaAsamblea/ComposiciondelaAsamblea/LosDiputados/Paginas/RelacionAlfabeticaDiputados.aspx']

    def parse(self, response):

         source  =   response
         hrefs   =   response.xpath("//*[@id='moduloBusqueda']//div[@class='sangria']/ul/li/a/@href").extract()
         form_data = self.validate(source)
         for ref in hrefs:
             # js2xml allows us to parse the JS function and params, and so to grab the __EVENTTARGET
             js_xml            = js2xml.parse(ref)
             _id               = js_xml.xpath(
                            "//identifier[@name='WebForm_PostBackOptions']/following-sibling::arguments/string[starts-with(.,'ctl')]")[0]
             form_data["__EVENTTARGET"] = _id.text

             url_diputado    =   'http://www.asambleamadrid.es/ES/QueEsLaAsamblea/ComposiciondelaAsamblea/LosDiputados/Paginas/RelacionAlfabeticaDiputados.aspx'
             # The proper way to send a POST in scrapy is by using the FormRequest
             yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=url_diputado, formdata=form_data, callback=self.extract_parties, method='POST')

     def validate(self, source):
         # these fields are the minimum required as cannot be hardcoded
         data = {"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": source.xpath("//*[@id='__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR']/@value")[0].extract(),
             "__EVENTVALIDATION": source.xpath("//*[@id='__EVENTVALIDATION']/@value")[0].extract(),
             "__VIEWSTATE": source.xpath("//*[@id='__VIEWSTATE']/@value")[0].extract(),
             " __REQUESTDIGEST": source.xpath("//*[@id='__REQUESTDIGEST']/@value")[0].extract()}
         return data

     def extract_parties(self, response):
         source      =   response
         name        =   source.xpath("//ul[@class='listadoVert02']/ul/li/a/text()").extract()
         print name
```

I hope is clear. Thanks everybody, again!

Comment: you'll need to check which actual requests are being done when yo do any action to replicate them with scrapy, and which request comes with the response that has the information you want, I would recommend using `Firebug` for firefox or developer tools on chrome. 

If you want to emulate a browser, please try selenium

Comment: as eLRuLL said, you can use selenium for this to emulate a click or if you want to keep scrapy you can use splash with docker. Never tried for click emulating but for loading javascript works like a charm.

Comment: Sure, okay. I will try with Selenium then. Anyway, with the code I wrote I'm getting an error 500, that means I'm sending wrong my POST parameters. Maybe I'm just missing something stupid. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the data posted to the form in chrome or firebug you can see there are many fields passed in the post request, there are a few that are essential and must be parsed from the original page, parsing the ids from the  `div.sangria ul li a` tags is not sufficient as the actual data posted is slightly different, what is posted is in the Javascript function, `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions` which is in the *href* not the *id* attribute:

```
href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new 
 WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$m$g_36ea0310_893d_4a19_9ed1_88a133d06423$ctl00$Repeater1$ctl03$lnk_Grupo", "", true, "", "", false, true))'>
```

Sometimes all the underscores are replaced with dollar signs so it is easy to do a *str.replace* to get them in the correct order but not really in this case, we could use a regex to parse but I like the [js2xml](https://github.com/redapple/js2xml) lib which can parse a javascript function and its args into an xml tree.

The following code using requests shows you how can get the data from  the initial request and get to all the pages you want:

```
import requests
from  lxml import html
import js2xml

post = "http://www.asambleamadrid.es/ES/QueEsLaAsamblea/ComposiciondelaAsamblea/LosDiputados/Paginas/RelacionAlfabeticaDiputados.aspx"


def validate(xml):
    # these fields are the minimum required as cannot be hardcoded
    data = {"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": xml.xpath("//*[@id='__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR']/@value")[0],
            "__EVENTVALIDATION": xml.xpath("//*[@id='__EVENTVALIDATION']/@value")[0],
            "__VIEWSTATE": xml.xpath("//*[@id='__VIEWSTATE']/@value")[0],
            " __REQUESTDIGEST": xml.xpath("//*[@id='__REQUESTDIGEST']/@value")[0]}
    return data



with requests.Session() as s:
    # make initial requests to get the links/hrefs and the from fields
    r = s.get(
        "http://www.asambleamadrid.es/ES/QueEsLaAsamblea/ComposiciondelaAsamblea/LosDiputados/Paginas/RelacionAlfabeticaDiputados.aspx")
    xml = html.fromstring(r.content)
    hrefs = xml.xpath("//*[@id='moduloBusqueda']//div[@class='sangria']/ul/li/a/@href")
    form_data = validate(xml)
    for h in hrefs:
        js_xml = js2xml.parse(h)
        _id = js_xml.xpath(
            "//identifier[@name='WebForm_PostBackOptions']/following-sibling::arguments/string[starts-with(.,'ctl')]")[
            0]
        form_data["__EVENTTARGET"] = _id.text
        r = s.post(post, data=form_data)
        xml = html.fromstring(r.content)
        print(xml.xpath("//ul[@class='listadoVert02']/ul/li/a/text()"))
```

If we run the code above we see the different text output from all teh anchor tags:

```
In [2]: with requests.Session() as s:
   ...:         r = s.get(
   ...:             "http://www.asambleamadrid.es/ES/QueEsLaAsamblea/ComposiciondelaAsamblea/LosDiputados/Paginas/RelacionAlfabeticaDiputados.aspx")
   ...:         xml = html.fromstring(r.content)
   ...:         hrefs = xml.xpath("//*[@id='moduloBusqueda']//div[@class='sangria']/ul/li/a/@href")
   ...:         form_data = validate(xml)
   ...:         for h in hrefs:
   ...:                 js_xml = js2xml.parse(h)
   ...:                 _id = js_xml.xpath(
   ...:                     "//identifier[@name='WebForm_PostBackOptions']/following-sibling::arguments/string[starts-with(.,'ctl')]")[
   ...:                     0]
   ...:                 form_data["__EVENTTARGET"] = _id.text
   ...:                 r = s.post(post, data=form_data)
   ...:                 xml = html.fromstring(r.content)
   ...:                 print(xml.xpath("//ul[@class='listadoVert02']/ul/li/a/text()"))
   ...:         
[u'Abo\xedn Abo\xedn, Sonsoles Trinidad', u'Adrados Gautier, M\xaa Paloma', u'Aguado Del Olmo, M\xaa Josefa', u'\xc1lvarez Padilla, M\xaa Nadia', u'Arribas Del Barrio, Jos\xe9 M\xaa', u'Ballar\xedn Valc\xe1rcel, \xc1lvaro C\xe9sar', u'Berrio Fern\xe1ndez-Caballero, M\xaa In\xe9s', u'Berzal Andrade, Jos\xe9 Manuel', u'Cam\xedns Mart\xednez, Ana', u'Carballedo Berlanga, M\xaa Eugenia', 'Cifuentes Cuencas, Cristina', u'D\xedaz Ayuso, Isabel Natividad', u'Escudero D\xedaz-Tejeiro, Marta', u'Fermosel D\xedaz, Jes\xfas', u'Fern\xe1ndez-Quejo Del Pozo, Jos\xe9 Luis', u'Garc\xeda De Vinuesa Gardoqui, Ignacio', u'Garc\xeda Mart\xedn, Mar\xeda Bego\xf1a', u'Garrido Garc\xeda, \xc1ngel', u'G\xf3mez Ruiz, Jes\xfas', u'G\xf3mez-Angulo Rodr\xedguez, Juan Antonio', u'Gonz\xe1lez Gonz\xe1lez, Isabel Gema', u'Gonz\xe1lez Jim\xe9nez, Bartolom\xe9', u'Gonz\xe1lez Taboada, Jaime', u'Gonz\xe1lez-Mo\xf1ux V\xe1zquez, Elena', u'Gonzalo L\xf3pez, Rosal\xeda', 'Izquierdo Torres, Carlos', u'Li\xe9bana Montijano, Pilar', u'Mari\xf1o Ortega, Ana Isabel', u'Moraga Valiente, \xc1lvaro', u'Mu\xf1oz Abrines, Pedro', u'N\xfa\xf1ez Guijarro, Jos\xe9 Enrique', u'Olmo Fl\xf3rez, Luis Del', u'Ongil Cores, M\xaa Gador', 'Ortiz Espejo, Daniel', u'Ossorio Crespo, Enrique Mat\xedas', 'Peral Guerra, Luis', u'P\xe9rez Baos, Ana Isabel', u'P\xe9rez Garc\xeda, David', u'Pla\xf1iol De Lacalle, Regina M\xaa', u'Redondo Alcaide, M\xaa Isabel', u'Roll\xe1n Ojeda, Pedro', u'S\xe1nchez Fern\xe1ndez, Alejandro', 'Sanjuanbenito Bonal, Diego', u'Serrano Guio, Jos\xe9 Tom\xe1s', u'Serrano S\xe1nchez-Capuchino, Alfonso Carlos', 'Soler-Espiauba Gallo, Juan', 'Toledo Moreno, Lucila', 'Van-Halen Acedo, Juan']
[u'Andaluz Andaluz, M\xaa Isabel', u'Ardid Jim\xe9nez, M\xaa Isabel', u'Carazo G\xf3mez, M\xf3nica', u'Casares D\xedaz, M\xaa Luc\xeda Inmaculada', u'Cepeda Garc\xeda De Le\xf3n, Jos\xe9 Carmelo', 'Cruz Torrijos, Diego', u'Delgado G\xf3mez, Carla', u'Franco Pardo, Jos\xe9 Manuel', u'Freire Campo, Jos\xe9 Manuel', u'Gabilondo Pujol, \xc1ngel', 'Gallizo Llamas, Mercedes', u"Garc\xeda D'Atri, Ana", u'Garc\xeda-Rojo Garrido, Pedro Pablo', u'G\xf3mez Montoya, Rafael', u'G\xf3mez-Chamorro Torres, Jos\xe9 \xc1ngel', u'Gonz\xe1lez Gonz\xe1lez, M\xf3nica Silvana', u'Leal Fern\xe1ndez, M\xaa Isaura', u'Llop Cuenca, M\xaa Pilar', 'Lobato Gandarias, Juan', u'L\xf3pez Ruiz, M\xaa Carmen', u'Manguan Valderrama, Eva M\xaa', u'Maroto Illera, M\xaa Reyes', u'Mart\xednez Ten, Carmen', u'Mena Romero, M\xaa Carmen', u'Moreno Navarro, Juan Jos\xe9', u'Moya Nieto, Encarnaci\xf3n', 'Navarro Lanchas, Josefa', 'Nolla Estrada, Modesto', 'Pardo Ortiz, Josefa Dolores', u'Quintana Viar, Jos\xe9', u'Rico Garc\xeda-Hierro, Enrique', u'Rodr\xedguez Garc\xeda, Nicol\xe1s', u'S\xe1nchez Acera, Pilar', u'Sant\xedn Fern\xe1ndez, Pedro', 'Segovia Noriega, Juan', 'Vicente Viondi, Daniel', u'Vinagre Alc\xe1zar, Agust\xedn']
['Abasolo Pozas, Olga', 'Ardanuy Pizarro, Miguel', u'Beirak Ulanosky, Jazm\xedn', u'Camargo Fern\xe1ndez, Ra\xfal', 'Candela Pokorna, Marco', 'Delgado Orgaz, Emilio', u'D\xedaz Rom\xe1n, Laura', u'Espinar Merino, Ram\xf3n', u'Espinosa De La Llave, Mar\xeda', u'Fern\xe1ndez Rubi\xf1o, Eduardo', u'Garc\xeda G\xf3mez, M\xf3nica', 'Gimeno Reinoso, Beatriz', u'Guti\xe9rrez Benito, Eduardo', 'Huerta Bravo, Raquel', u'L\xf3pez Hern\xe1ndez, Isidro', u'L\xf3pez Rodrigo, Jos\xe9 Manuel', u'Mart\xednez Abarca, Hugo', u'Morano Gonz\xe1lez, Jacinto', u'Ongil L\xf3pez, Miguel', 'Padilla Estrada, Pablo', u'Ruiz-Huerta Garc\xeda De Viedma, Lorena', 'Salazar-Alonso Revuelta, Cecilia', u'San Jos\xe9 P\xe9rez, Carmen', u'S\xe1nchez P\xe9rez, Alejandro', u'Serra S\xe1nchez, Isabel', u'Serra S\xe1nchez, Clara', 'Sevillano De Las Heras, Elena']
[u'Aguado Crespo, Ignacio Jes\xfas', u'\xc1lvarez Cabo, Daniel', u'Gonz\xe1lez Pastor, Dolores', u'Iglesia Vicente, M\xaa Teresa De La', 'Lara Casanova, Francisco', u'Marb\xe1n De Frutos, Marta', u'Marcos Arias, Tom\xe1s', u'Meg\xedas Morales, Jes\xfas Ricardo', u'N\xfa\xf1ez S\xe1nchez, Roberto', 'Reyero Zubiri, Alberto', u'Rodr\xedguez Dur\xe1n, Ana', u'Rubio Ruiz, Juan Ram\xf3n', u'Ruiz Fern\xe1ndez, Esther', u'Sol\xeds P\xe9rez, Susana', 'Trinidad Martos, Juan', 'Veloso Lozano, Enrique', u'Zafra Hern\xe1ndez, C\xe9sar']
```

You can add the exact same logic to your spider, I just used requests to show you a working example. You should also be aware that not every asp.net site behaves the same, you may have to re-validate for every post as in this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724326/making-subsequent-post-request-in-session-doesnt-work-web-scraping/36725215#36725215).

Comment: OUuaaa! Awesome! This is just what I needed! Thank you very much! It really solves my need of getting the strings dinamically :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that scrapy's `from_response` could help you a lot (maybe this isn't the best re but for it, but you'll get the idea), try something like this:

```
import scrapy
import urllib
from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest


class AsambleaMadrid(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Asamblea_Madrid"
    start_urls = ['http://www.asambleamadrid.es/ES/QueEsLaAsamblea/ComposiciondelaAsamblea/LosDiputados/Paginas/RelacionAlfabeticaDiputados.aspx']

    def parse(self, response):
        ids_re = r'WebForm_PostBackOptions\(([^,]*)'
        for id in response.css('#moduloBusqueda li a').re(ids_re):
            target = urllib.unquote(id).strip('"')
            formdata = {'__EVENTTARGET': target}
            request = FormRequest.from_response(response=response,
                                                formdata=formdata,
                                                callback=self.takeEachParty,
                                                dont_click=True)
            yield request

    def takeEachParty(self, response):
        print response.css('.listadoVert02 li a::text').extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with ASP.NET sites is using `scrapy.FormRequest` class. You don't have to worry about keeping track of the variables starting with `__` [someone please edit and write the actual technical term].

`The FormRequest class extends the base Request with functionality for dealing with HTML forms. It uses lxml.html forms to pre-populate form fields with form data from Response objects.` Source: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html

Here is how you can use it for your project - follow this tutorial:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTKL2qTw2Rc
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ATpE8T-nfY4

Answer (score -1):

Do agree with ELRuLL -  Firebug is your best friend while scraping.
If you want to avoid JS simulation then you need reproduce carefully all the params/headers that are being sent.

For example from what I see
for __EVENTTARGET you're sending just 
    `id="ctl00_m_g_36ea0310_893d_4a19_9ed1_88a133d06423_ctl00_Repeater2_ctl01_lnk_Diputado")`

and via Firebug we see that:

```
__EVENTTARGET=ctl00$m$g_36ea0310_893d_4a19_9ed1_88a133d06423$ctl00$Repeater2$ctl01$lnk_Diputado
```

[image: Form in firebug]
It maybe the reason and maybe not, just repeat and test.

[Firebug link](http://getfirebug.com/whatisfirebug) just in case.

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful. The thing is, if I can't find my EVENTTARGET so simply, how I'm supposed to find them dinamically to scrap the website? Is there any way to retrieve all those parameters via Python?

Comment: EVENTTARGET is the same as id, just with one replacement. So I would start with `target.replace('_','$')`. Usually they are either stored in html/js, or in Cookies, or generated on the fly (the trickiest case, here you would need to consider Selenium or Splash).