# payload to login in pag with user

Tags: python, payload

I'm trying to authenticate my user to extract prices.
But this does not work. and several probe .
I spent the whole day with the "# $ % & / program .
can u help me ?

tks

```
import requests

 payload = {
'txtNickName': 'estdddredfdde@gmail.com',
'inUserPass': 'edddddddddn1'
}


p = s.post('http://www.grupsssssso.com.ar/losssin/d=2/Distssssdora.aspx', data=payload)

print p.text


r = s.get('http://www.grssscleo.com.ar/MISDAsssNTA/c=114114/Distsssra.aspx')
print r.text
```

Comment: what is the url ?Also I resume s is meant to be a Session? I see aspx do I would be pretty confident you need _eventValidations tokens set etc..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577405/scrapy-crawling-not-working-on-aspx-website/37603423#37603423

Comment: http://gruponucleo.com.ar/login/d=2/Distribuidora.aspx this is the website.

Comment: I searched the website tokes of authentication , etc. but I found nothing to know how I can use to log in

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE_KEY" id="__VIEWSTATE_KEY" value="13bf3d0f-e216-4dc5-8d4e-c7253aa2763c" />
<input type="hidden" name="__SESSION_KEY" id="__SESSION_KEY" value="71e7f0eb-02ab-4679-8453-ca5217ff43d3" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="