# How to use the form data for login to the website

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am creating an application for my university in which students has to login as to get his data.The site posts the params like this[image]

---

**content from that page that post the params.**

```
<input checked="checked" id="SchSel_chkSkip" name="SchSel$chkSkip" type="checkbox"/>
 <input id="SchSel_hidLastLogin" name="SchSel$hidLastLogin" type="hidden"/>
 <input id="SchSel_hidSchoolId" name="SchSel$hidSchoolId" type="hidden" value="-1"/>
 <input id="SchSel_hidSchoolName" name="SchSel$hidSchoolName" type="hidden"/>
 <input id="SchSel_hidCoreUserDet" name="SchSel$hidCoreUserDet" type="hidden"/>
 <input id="SchSel_hidSessionId" name="SchSel$hidSessionId" type="hidden" value="-1"/>
 <input id="SchSel_hidActiveSchool" name="SchSel$hidActiveSchool" type="hidden" value="-1"/>
 <input id="SchSel_hidReportingDet" name="SchSel$hidReportingDet" type="hidden" value="-1"/>
 <input id="SchSel_hidActiveSession" name="SchSel$hidActiveSession" type="hidden" value="-1"/>
 <input id="SchSel_hidHitCount" name="SchSel$hidHitCount" type="hidden" value="378284"/>
 <input id="SchSel_hidSchoolAddress" name="SchSel$hidSchoolAddress" type="hidden" value="0"/>
 <input id="SchSel_hdnLoginAsUser" name="SchSel$hdnLoginAsUser" type="hidden"/>
```

The only data I know is SchSel$txtUserName and SchSel$txtPassword which i can post but how to get other values

---

**What I tried :**

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
url = 'https://nucleus.niituniversity.in/Default.aspx'
login_data = {'ScriptManager1' : 'SchSel$up|SchSel$btnLogin',
          '__LASTFOCUS' : '',
          '__EVENTTARGET' : '',
          '__EVENTARGUMENT' : '',
          '__VIEWSTATE' :   '/wEPDwUKMTg3OTYzNDk4Nw9kFgICAw9kFhICAQ8PFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZGQCAg8PFgIfAGhkZAIDDwdkxvZ2luDw9kZmQaZNVi16vCv',
          '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' : 'CA0B0334',
          'SchSel$cmbUserType' : 'Student',
          'SchSel$txtUserName' : 'user',
          'SchSel$txtPassword' : '1234',
          'SchSel$chkSkip' : 'on',
          'SchSel$hidLastLogin' : '2016-2017',
          'SchSel$hidSchoolId' : '1',
          'SchSel$hidSchoolName' : 'School name',
          'SchSel$hidCoreUserDet' : '815106',
          'SchSel$hidSessionId' : '8',
          'SchSel$hidActiveSchool' : '1',
          'SchSel$hidReportingDet' : '0',
          'SchSel$hidActiveSession' : '1',
          'SchSel$hidHitCount' : '3',
          'SchSel$hidSchoolAddress' : 'Address',
          'SchSel$hdnLoginAsUser' : '',
          '__ASYNCPOST' : 'true',
          'SchSel$btnLogin.x' : '42',
          'SchSel$btnLogin.y' : '14'
            }
s.post(url,data = login_data)

res = s.get('Protected page')
```

But failed to login.why it is failing though i am posting the required data.?

Comment: Because you cannot use the the values from your browser, you need to parse them from your session http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577405/scrapy-crawling-not-working-on-aspx-website/37603423#37603423

Comment: What headers are you passing?

Comment: User-Agent :Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0,cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=ow0xuxtckpa5aksglq0o5ngl

Comment: I don't know what's wrong.I've tried all.

Comment: try http://pastebin.com/hdBSVyqg

Comment: not working.error-`chkSkip = soup.select_one("#SchSel_chkSkip")["value"]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 958, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'value'`

Comment: this is the site I am trying to login.you can get what's wrong exactly please visit .-https://nucleus.niituniversity.in

Comment: interesting, what parser are you using?

Comment: Try using with html.parser or if you have lxml use that, the code should have no issue parsing the value

Comment: done.nothing changed.I think the problem is with as soon as i enter the username manually in the site it sends a get request like this `https://nucleus.niituniversity.in/GetLoginData.aspx?username=u101114fcs059&categoryid=3&URL=https://nucleus.niituniversity.in/&TIME=Thu Aug 04 2016 16:09:33 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` If this happens only the site is generating the schoolId and schoolName etc and other values.otherwise it returns -1 for all values

Comment: can you please visit this link - `https://nucleus.niituniversity.in` and see requests in Inspect element's networks panel.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham can you please help me to sort this out.?this is driving me crazy since 2 days