# sending raw data in python requests

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I'm trying to send a POST request with python requests, containing the following data:

```
__VIEWSTATE=%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%2FRQ%2BPP7XKuKE1Yc7MfMt6j3NmJGEldOg%3D%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=98F5786E&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWPwLc4fuhDgLPv6LBCALyveCRDwKt9JiEDQKyzcaDDQLQzfKVCgLi0PKVCgKwgbuWDQK4qIuIDAKDhrjXCAKT%2B%2B00AqGSlqELAoPh28wDAvSit9QCAsvep4YKAtj71VwC9pD07goC8rfjvgoCoryYqAECv6uC5A4C2dmTnQUCrdnKtgICyJiTrwsCjLGlBQKNsaUFAo6xpQUCj7GlBQKIsaUFAomxpQUCirGlBQKbsaUFApSxpQUCjLHlBgKMsekGAoyx7QYCjLHRBgKMsdUGAoyx2QYCjLHdBgKMscEGAoyxhQUCjLGJBQKNseUGAo2x6QYCjbHtBgKNsdEGAo2x1QYCjbHZBgKNsd0GAo2xwQYCjbGFBQKNsYkFAo6x5QYCjrHpBgLopM%2F9CwLsyZauAQL4oO3lBAK8yuqBCwL1hriZBwLUpvv7CALsqKmSDgLqoY%2BHAwLCi9reA5HII3R9bARNVKmrB9WBnfeJepHFJrdPAtcLnXlE%2BdKP&username2=gfk7ljlyks&password=boolbool1&password2=boolbool1&email=myeail%40gf.com&fname=&lname=&phone=&street=&city=&BYear=&Bmonth=%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%90%D7%A8&Bday=1&career=&signature=&homepage=&icq=&Morehobbies=&allowmail=on&SendNews=on&chkterms=on&btnSubmit=%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%A5+%D7%9C%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D+%D7%94%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%94+%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%AA%D7%A8
```

but as I see in the documentation, the only option is to add the data as a `dict` (which wouldn't work with that data for some reason)

Anyone has an idea how to send this data properly? (should result a 302)
or even better, anyone knows how to turn this data in to a `dict` ?

Comment: You are trying to parse an aspx page? regardless `data = dict(s.split("=", 1))`. This you may also find useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577405/scrapy-crawling-not-working-on-aspx-website/37603423#37603423

Comment: I have the data in a dict format as well, but it also returns a 200 instead of a 302. that we I considered the option that im formatting it wrong, turns out its not the case.

Comment: Ah ok, I see all the from fields are in there, can you share the url you are posting to? I think you will most likely need more that t just post the data you see there.

Comment: you cannot copy/paste what you see in your browser and expect it to work, use the logic in the link I posted in the first comment.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There's no issue sending raw post data:

```
raw_data = '__VIEWSTATE=%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%2FRQ%2BPP7XKuKE1Yc7MfMt6j3NmJGEldOg%3D%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=98F5786E&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWPwLc4fuhDgLPv6LBCALyveCRDwKt9JiEDQKyzcaDDQLQzfKVCgLi0PKVCgKwgbuWDQK4qIuIDAKDhrjXCAKT%2B%2B00AqGSlqELAoPh28wDAvSit9QCAsvep4YKAtj71VwC9pD07goC8rfjvgoCoryYqAECv6uC5A4C2dmTnQUCrdnKtgICyJiTrwsCjLGlBQKNsaUFAo6xpQUCj7GlBQKIsaUFAomxpQUCirGlBQKbsaUFApSxpQUCjLHlBgKMsekGAoyx7QYCjLHRBgKMsdUGAoyx2QYCjLHdBgKMscEGAoyxhQUCjLGJBQKNseUGAo2x6QYCjbHtBgKNsdEGAo2x1QYCjbHZBgKNsd0GAo2xwQYCjbGFBQKNsYkFAo6x5QYCjrHpBgLopM%2F9CwLsyZauAQL4oO3lBAK8yuqBCwL1hriZBwLUpvv7CALsqKmSDgLqoY%2BHAwLCi9reA5HII3R9bARNVKmrB9WBnfeJepHFJrdPAtcLnXlE%2BdKP&username2=gfk7ljlyks&password=boolbool1&password2=boolbool1&email=myeail%40gf.com&fname=&lname=&phone=&street=&city=&BYear=&Bmonth=%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%90%D7%A8&Bday=1&career=&signature=&homepage=&icq=&Morehobbies=&allowmail=on&SendNews=on&chkterms=on&btnSubmit=%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%A5+%D7%9C%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D+%D7%94%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%94+%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%AA%D7%A8'
requests.post(url, data=raw_data)
```

A minor bonus is that your data is already percent encoded.

From the doc string:

```
post(url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs)
    Sends a POST request.

    :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
    :param data: (optional) Dictionary, bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
    :param json: (optional) json data to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
    :param \*\*kwargs: Optional arguments that ``request`` takes.
    :return: :class:`Response <Response>` object
    :rtype: requests.Response
```

So `data` can be a dictionary, string/bytes, or a file-like object.

Perhaps you need to specify the `Content-Type` header like this:

```
requests.post(url, data=raw_data, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: maybe, I don't know where the data comes from. I just wanted to point out that `requests.post()` supports sending of strings and that a dict is not required. But if it comes from a form, perhaps the OP only needs to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Well +1 anyway, it answers the literal question but I think the OP is asking the wrong one.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: thanks. I think you're right, OP needs to parse the fields and values out of the initial page.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
you can geenrate the code form postman itself in postman:

**To send from python POST request:**

```
def send_data(*args):
    import requests
    from datetime import datetime
    try:
        headers = {
            'HodHodApiKey': args[5],
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        timeDate = args[2].strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
        # print("Inside API::", timeDate)
        payload = '{\"cameraId\":"'+str(args[0])+'",\"picture\": "'+str(args[1])+'",\"timeDate\":"'+str(timeDate)+'",\"voilationName\": "'+str(args[3])+'"\r\n\t}'

        result = requests.post(args[4],data=payload,headers=headers)

        print("Result: ", result)
        lJsonResult = result.json()

        print("lJsonResult", lJsonResult)
        # print(result.status_code)
        if result.status_code == 201:
            print(" Added DataName.. ")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to send New data to server....", e)
```